# How to rotate a "+" to an "x" using CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created an accordion using HTML, JS and CSS. However, when you click on the accordion the "+" doesn't turn correctly as it rotates from the top of the "+" sign not the middle of the "+" sign.

My HTML:

```
<div class="acc">
  <div class="acc-titel">Graphic Designer - London</div>
  <div class="acc-content">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.acc-titel {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #08455c;
  transition: background 0.1s ease, transform 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #08455c;
}

.acc-titel:after {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  font-weight: 100;
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  color: #08455c;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 1);
}

.acc-titel:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.active:after {
  content: "+";
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

.acc-content {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(5px);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease, opacity 0.8s ease, transform 0.8s ease;
}
.acc-content p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

The codepen to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/LBazMm

Comment: Have checked out `transform-origin: 50% 50%;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default rotation point is the centre of the element. Your problem is because you've set the element too small, so the centre point is not the centre of the `X`, so it appears to orbit the centre.

To fix this, remove the `width` and `height` CSS properties from `.acc-titel:after`

```js
var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("acc-titel");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
  accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var showContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (showContent.style.maxHeight) {
      showContent.style.maxHeight = null;
      showContent.style.opacity = null;
      showContent.style.transform = "translateY(5px)";
    } else {
      showContent.style.maxHeight = showContent.scrollHeight + "px";
      showContent.style.opacity = "1";
      showContent.style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.acc-titel {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #08455c;
  transition: background 0.1s ease, transform 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #08455c;
}

.acc-titel:after {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  font-weight: 100;
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  color: #08455c;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 1);  
}

.acc-titel:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.active:after {
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

.acc-content {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(5px);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease, opacity 0.8s ease, transform 0.8s ease;
}

.acc-content p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="acc">
  <div class="acc-titel">Graphic Designer - London</div>
  <div class="acc-content">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help